# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror

```
def shop1():
    kitchen_shopping = Toplevel()
    kitchen_shopping.title('Kitchen Shelves, Shelves, Shelves...!')
    kitchen_shopping = open('Static Pages/kitchenshelf.html', 'r')
    kitchen_list_items = Text(kitchen_shopping, width = 30, height = 10,
                                 borderwidth = 2, relief = 'groove')
    kitchen_list_items.pack(kitchen_shopping)   
    kitchen_items = findall(r'<title>\s<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>', kitchen_shopping.read())
    return print(kitchen_items)
```

So my problem is that I'm trying to read a **HTML** document and return all the **'Titles'**. Obviously in future I want this to be formatted into the text box "kitchen_list_items" but for now i'm just trying to get it to print. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: Your Toplevel is called `kitchen_shopping` and your file is _also_ called `kitchen_shopping`.

Comment: my file is called "online_shopping_app"

Comment: `kitchen_shopping = open('Static Pages/kitchenshelf.html', 'r')`

Comment: Oh, silly me, that did fix one problem, but it still isnt printing :/ !

Comment: You are giving `pack()` the argument `kitchen_shopping`. Pack does not take master as an argument.